# Box inside an image - find what is not contained in that box and replace with zeroes (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to replace, with zeroes, all elements of array that don't exist in seconds array.
I got an array of RGBA image:

```
 [[101 120 115 255]
  [101 120 115 255]
  [101 120 115 255]
  ...
  [113 127 124 255]
  [112 126 123 255]
  [109 123 120 255]]
```

Then i got a variables X, Y and Height and Width of box that is contained inside that picture. With that variables, I am trying to replace everything that is not inside that box to white.

I got coordinates X, Y, Width, Height of white box inside black box (look at the picture below) and i want to replace everything that is not in that bounding box with 0. How could I do it?

[image]

Comment: `yourArr[X:X + width,Y:Y + height] = 0` ?

Comment: I am trying to the reverse of what you wrote.

I got x,y, w, h of white box you can see on the picture and i want to change everything that is not inside that bounding box to 0

Comment: See my answer @NiewaszBiznes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a matrix of `0`, put `1` inside the "white box" indices, and multiply them. This will result in all other indices containing `0`.

```
tmp = np.zeros_like(yourArr)
tmp[X:X + width,Y:Y + height] = 1
yourArr = yourArr * tmp
```